# Замена параметров в webbrowser/ cefsharp c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser, cefsharp

Добрый день, интересует такой вопрос, можно ли в `webbrowser` или в `cefsharp` и подобных браузерах для `c#` изменить передаваемые параметры ? например : разрешение экрана, используемые плагины, юзерагент,таймзона и тп.

Через тот же `xNEt` все это вроде как можно подменить, но интересует именно браузеры. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: У вас какой-то слишком общий вопрос, неясно что именно нужно.

Comment: В целом, уверен, что как минимум большинство что у вас описано можно сделать или напрямую, или придумать обходные пути. Но если вы расчитываете, что будут примеры кода на каждый из пунктов, то очень удивлюсь если кто-то этим заморочится.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov понял, буду тогда спрашивать по каждому пункту отдельно, с которым сам не справлюсь, спасибо